# Converting docker run to YAML for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I'm new to Kubernetes. I'm trying to convert the following DOCKER container code to YAML for kubernetes.

```
docker container run -d -p 80:80 --name MyFirstContainerWeb docker/getting-started:pwd
```

This is what I have come up with so far. Can someone please help me with the ingress part? I'm using Docker Desktop (which has kubernetes cluster). My final goal is to see the website in the browser.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: getting-started-deployment 
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: getting-started 
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: getting-started
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: getting-started-container 
        image: docker/getting-started:pwd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: getting-started-service 
   namespace: default
   labels:
     app: myfirstcontainer
 spec:
   ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 80
     targetPort: 80
   selector:
     app: getting-started-service
```

Comment: have you tried using a NodePort? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Comment: also have you tried running this? What sort of responses do you get?

Comment: @VincentRodomista when I run this deployment gets created. However, I can't access http://localhost:80 from the web browser. 

I have not used NodePort. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use port-forward to forward to service port by running

```
$ kubectl port-forward svc/getting-started-service 80
```

To learn more about port-forwarding click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: Thank you. When I try to port forwarding, I get this exception: error: timed out waiting for the condition

Comment: In your service please modify selector as `app: getting-started`. It should match with deployment.spec.template.metadata.labels

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much kind sir.

Comment: Two quick questions: 1. Can we place the IP forwarding inside the YAML file? 
2.  when I did IP forwarding I see the below continuous loop at the command prompt. 
`Handling connection for 80
Handling connection for 80`
Is this Normal? If I ctrl+c out of it, the website stops. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes it's normal. you can use `NodePort` as your service type to use service using node's ip . check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.